# find average of columns of a 2d jagged array

Tags: java

I am trying to find the averages of columns of a jagged array but I get an error saying that `arr[j].length` when I'm dividing it by the sum, the `j` cannot find symbol. What can I do to fix this problem?

```
int maxC = arr[0].length;
for (int a = 1; a < arr.length; a++){
    if (arr[a].length > maxC){
        maxC = arr[a].length;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < maxC; i++){
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
        if (i < arr[j].length){
            sum += arr[j][i];
        }
    }
    double avg = sum / arr[j].length;
    System.out.println("Average of col  " + (i + 1) +  "is: " + avg);  
}
```

Comment: `arr[j].length` is the wrong thing to divide by, anyway. You would be dividing by the length of one of the rows. You need to divide by the number of items in that column, which you need to keep track of while calculating the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `j` is declared in the inner for loop. Outside of that loop it does not exist. But the way I see it, you don't want to divide by the length of `arr[j]`, but by the number of numbers you added. That's `arr.length` minus the number of nested arrays that are too short.

The easiest way to fix this is to introduce a new variable that you increment inside your if statement, then divide by that variable instead of by `arr[j].length`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use `row`/`col` names instead of common `i`/`j` to improve code clarity.  Also, a separate counter for the columns is needed to increment only when a column is present in a row to properly calculate the average:

```java
for (int col = 0; col < maxC; col++) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    int colCount = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
        if (col < arr[row].length) {
            sum += arr[row][col];
            colCount++;
        }
    }
    double avg = sum / colCount;
    System.out.println("Average of col #" + (col + 1) +  " is: " + avg);  
}
```